# ¿Cómo separar una fila en varias filas en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola!, tengo una tabla que contiene la siguiente información de arriba, me gustaría dividirla en varias filas, específicamente separado por 4 columnas. La idea es que quedé algo así, ya que tengo varios registros, me podrían ayudar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto se ve como un simple `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT
    t1.Orden,
    t1.Indicador,
    t1.AñoAnterior,
    t1.AñoActual
FROM dbo.Tabla t1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    t2.Orden2,
    t2.Indicador2,
    t2.AñoAnterior2,
    t2.AñoActual2
FROM dbo.Tabla t2
;
```

Comment: Me funcionó, muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer eso de una forma más eficiente usando `CROSS APPLY` y el contructor de tablas `VALUES` para generar las filas.

```
SELECT
    tx.Orden,
    tx.Indicador,
    tx.AñoAnterior,
    tx.AñoActual
FROM dbo.Tabla t1
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (Orden, Indicador, AñoAnterior, AñoActual),
                    (Orden2, Indicador2, AñoAnterior2, AñoActual2))tx(Orden, Indicador, AñoAnterior, AñoActual);
```

Aunque también puedes usar `UNION ALL` en vez de `VALUES` para lograr el mismo efecto.

```
SELECT
    tx.Orden,
    tx.Indicador,
    tx.AñoAnterior,
    tx.AñoActual
FROM dbo.Tabla t1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Orden, Indicador, AñoAnterior, AñoActual UNION ALL
             SELECT Orden2, Indicador2, AñoAnterior2, AñoActual2)tx
```

Estas opciones son más eficientes porque no requieren que la tabla se lea 2 veces como ocurre al hacer directamente el `UNION ALL`.